# newtheorem wrong name error

Tags: newtheorem

Hello I wrote this new theorem into new blank overleaf project.

```
\newtheorem{graf}{Def}
\begin{graf}

\end{graf}
```

I dont know why but i get some weird error: **LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item**.
When I changed word "graf" for something else (for example "graph") everything worked fine.
In my old project, which I created year ago on overleaf, I used same code with "graf" and everything worked fine as well. Any idea, where is the problem?

Comment: `\end{graf}` will be defined by re-defining `\endgraf` which is a saved name for `\par` and everything will break

Answer (score 3):

`\end{graf}` will be defined by re-defining `\endgraf` which is a saved name for `\par` and everything will break.

Arguably `\newtheorem` should check the `\end...` name is not taken, but currently it doesn't.

See related issue

https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/570

```
\documentclass{article}
\show\endgraf
\newtheorem{graf}{Def}
\show\endgraf
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Produces terminal output:

```
> \endgraf=\protected\long macro:
->\scan_stop: \mode_if_horizontal:TF {\mode_if_inner:F {\tex_unskip:D \hook_use
:n {para/end}\@kernel@after@para@end \mode_if_horizontal:TF {\if_int_compare:w 
11=\tex_lastnodetype:D \tex_hskip:D \c_zero_dim \fi: \tex_par:D \hook_use:n {pa
ra/after}\@kernel@after@para@after }{\msg_error:nnnn {hooks}{para-mode}{end}{ho
rizontal}}}}\tex_par:D .
l.2 \show\endgraf
                 
? 
> \endgraf=macro:
->\@endtheorem .
l.4 \show\endgraf
                 
?
```